# Why was I charged twice?

Tags: banking, bank-account, debit-card, online-banking

I've got two line items in my "In Process Transactions" table via my online banking interface like this:

```
DEC 22 POS PUR **** [ITEM1]    $500.67
DEC 22 POS PUR **** [ITEM2]    $1000.29
```

Then above it (at the top), I've got these two line items:

```
DEC 23 Hold: Payee Name: $$$ ; Reason: EFT PCOMB HOLD FOR NEXT DAY AU $1000.29
DEC 23 Hold: Payee Name: $$$ ; Reason: EFT PCOMB HOLD FOR NEXT DAY AU $500.67
```

So, basically, it looks like this:

```
DEC 23 Hold: Payee Name: $$$ ; Reason: EFT PCOMB HOLD FOR NEXT DAY AU $1000.29
DEC 23 Hold: Payee Name: $$$ ; Reason: EFT PCOMB HOLD FOR NEXT DAY AU $500.67
DEC 22 POS PUR **** [ITEM1]    $500.67
DEC 22 POS PUR **** [ITEM2]    $1000.29
```

But, what's weird, or I guess what I'm not understanding, is that I have a debit of $3001.92, when I only bought ITEM 1 and ITEM 2. Oh, and by the way "****" is me redacting the actual 4-digit number that was on these line items, and "[ITEM1]" is me masking the actual item purchased, to be clear. Why is this so? These purchases happened today (the date of this post). Both items were purchased at different locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would read that as:

'POS' is the Point-Of-Sale recording, and
'Hold' is the holding back activity of the money (=the bank takes the amount out of your money).

This does not look like a duplicate charge, just two activities related to one sale.

Did you check your new total? Did it go down once or twice the spend amounts?

Comment: Ok, that's weird, it's gone today. I really don't like that this activity isn't indefinitely journaled and more specific. Oh yeah, and that these data are probably not accessible in the future without being charged a $50/h "research fee", so I have to backup every month.

Comment: Yes, it was two activities for one sale (for each), but they withheld double the amount. That is to say, were I to have exactly $3001.92 in the account, then I would not be able to make a purchase even though I really have $1500.96 (let's just forget that I have overdraft protection, etc.). Remember, that the day after I made this purchase, the secondary charge (the hold), was put back in my account. Am I loosing my mind? The numbers don't lie.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the first transaction was putting hold on your card because the purchase could not be completed right away, if so that hold should be released as soon as the actual transaction is completed.